# Upload app to appstore after Holiday shutdown

Tags: ios, app-store

Is it possible to upload an app to the appstore after apple started the holiday shutdown (December 21th)?

For example, if we decide to upload our first release on December 24th, what's gonna happen?

we want to have our app available on January 7th, do you guys think it's better to upload it prior to holiday shutdown?

Thank you guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you will not be able to upload your app after the shutdown. Either you can submit the app before 21 or after 28.

**Here is the list of things you cannot do during shutdown period:**

> iTunes Connect will be temporarily shut down from Friday, December 21,
>   2012 to Friday, December 28, 2012, for the winter holidays. During
>   this shutdown, the following functionality will be unavailable:
>
> Access to iTunes Connect Delivery of any apps or updates Additionally,
>   the following will be delayed:
>
> Releases scheduled to appear on the App Store for the first time
>   Pricing changes scheduled through the interval pricing system in
>   iTunes Connect We strongly recommend that you do not schedule any
>   pricing changes in iTunes Connect that would take effect between
>   Friday, December 21, 2012 and Friday, December 28, 2012. Pricing
>   changes scheduled to take effect during this date range will not be
>   reflected on the App Store and your app or In-App Purchase will become
>   unavailable for purchase until after the shutdown.
>
> We also recommend that you do not schedule any apps to go live during
>   the shutdown. Releases scheduled with a start date between Friday,
>   December 21, 2012 and Friday, December 28, 2012 will not go live on
>   the App Store until after the shutdown.

Comment: For 2015: https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Managing%20Your%20Apps_Submission%20Process#68611491